Manifest file does not exist ( Android Stuido )
im try to build Android App (Java APK)
I tried to build my own application, but I encountered several issues. I attempted to use the following settings, but the solutions did not work.
I facing this issue when I try run in emulator of Android Studio :
Manifest file does not exist: D:\AndroidStudioProjects\LabExploit\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

build.gradle
// Correct order of blocks in build.gradle
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google() // Always put google() first to ensure you get the latest artifacts
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4' // Use the appropriate version
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.0.4' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.0.4' apply false
}

// The rest of your build configuration
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // Add other dependencies as needed
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/aidl']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/main/rs']
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
        }

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }



    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/aidl']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/main/rs']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
        }

        debug.setRoot('src/debug')
        release.setRoot('src/release')
    }
}


and when try to build APK
<macro name="m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape">?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall</macro>

anyone can help me :) ?

Have you verified that there is an AndroidManifest.xml at the mentioned path?
